# Correct graphics for Android devices in regard to small/normal/large/xlarge and ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi?

Tags: android

Im new to Android development and Im still a bit confused about making the correct graphics for the different devices. In [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence) there is a table listing different screen resolutions and density but it confuses me... Now lets take a example. I need a full screen background for my app, so making the largest background image 800x1280 for Galaxy Note seems about right for me (I don't want to support tablets, only phones), and then I could make a 720x1280 for Galaxy S3 and its likes and 480x800 version for Galaxy S2 and its likes, but where should I then place those image files?

It seems to me that all those devices are in the high density range, but then how do the devices use the correct graphics? Should I manually control this, or should I simply use just one and the same graphics for all devices and let Android scale it (then there are the problem with aspect ratio, how do I overcome that?)?

Thank you

Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In resource folder, you can create drawable directories according to width/height.
Then, you can use resource qualifiers, for width - wdp or Examples: w720dp,w1024dp etc.
for height hdp. Examples:h720dp, h1024dp etc.

Alternatively you can categories Screen size as small, normal, and large and can place your images in respective drawables.

Refer to this post : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules

**small**:  QVGA low density and VGA high density.

**normal**: WQVGA low density, HVGA medium density, WVGA high density.

**large**:  VGA and WVGA medium density screens.

**xlarge**: HVGA screen. The minimum layout size for an xlarge screen is approximately 720x960 dp units.

Everything is provided at developer site. Please refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ScreenSizeQualifier)

Comment: So I could make these directories: drawable-w800dp, drawable-w720dp and drawable-w480dp and it would work because it uses the one that fits the width best? About the small,normal,large identifiers how do they actually work? It seems from the table that the 480x800 high dpi would be normal but what about the 720x1280 high dpi?

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by yogeshhkumarr is correct, but it is worth noting that, depending on what sort of background images you are using, you may be able to make use of a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) image to solve your problem without having to make multiple versions of the same image.